# What does the read contact permission really mean in Android 5.x?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, privacy

I've been playing around with the [XPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) module [ProtectMyPrivaccy](https://repo.xposed.info/module/org.synergylabs.pmpandroid), and I noticed that [Offline Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navigation.offlinemaps.gps&hl=en_US) requires "read contacts" permission when doing a POI (Point Of Interest) search.

I can see how someone might enter a contacts address there, though I never would have thought of that.  However, it seems the POI search fails completely when the app does not have the contact read permission.

I know they (Android/Google) grouped the permissions too large, so I'm guessing that "read contacts" really means "read stuff out of any of the myriad of databases on the phone".  Is that true?

Comment: I don't think so, and would rather suspect a "wrong implementation". Have you contacted the developer already?

Comment: No.  While the PMP dev might be responsive, I would not expect much from the Offline Maps team.  "Don't purposefully break our stuff" is what I'd expect a response to be.

Comment: You're probably right there. I've never used PMP, so I don't know what exactly it is blocking. I'm with XPrivacy(Lua) and LOS's Privacy Guard. What if you just claim you didn't grant the Contacts permission? That should be perfectly legit even for them (of course I count your measures "perfectly legit" as well, but "they" might disagree).